# 「は」と「を」の違いは何ですか。

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-を

私の日本語の本によると、「を」の代わりに「は」を使う事が出来ます。でも、いつ使えますか。ニュアンスは何が変わりますか。

例えば:

> 1. 肉を食べますか → 肉は食べますか。
> 2. 子供たちはカレーを作っている。→ カレーは子供たちが作っている。

Answer (score 3):

１の例について言うと、主題がない（ように見える）疑問文である「肉を食べますか」は数ある食べものの中から肉を選ぶかを聞いてます。いわゆる排他の「が」。

それに対して主題がある文は、1. 一般的なことを言ったり（総記）2.（主題の切り替えによって）何か他のものとの対比を表します。つまり、「肉は食べますか」は、1. 普段肉を食べるか、肉を食べる習慣があるかどうか、または、2. 他の食べものについては食べたり食べなかったりすることがわかったとして、では肉についてはどうかを問う表現になります。

主題がない平叙文には「排他」の他に、新しく見聞きしたことを表現する文である「現象文」もありますが、これは、疑問文では文の * 主語を無助詞で表します。つまり、**今、肉を食べるかどうか**聞くときは「**肉、食べますか**」といいます。（* この点、節では助詞がつきます。つまり、この例で「肉を食べるか、それとも…どうしますか」ということはできます。）なお、外国人向けの教材ではこの例で「肉を食べますか」としてしまっていることが多いですが、口語日本語の例として不自然です。

Answer (score 0):

簡単に言うと、助詞の使い方で文の色んな部分を強調することができる。

> 例１：子供たちはカレーを作っている。 --> 子供たちは**何をしている**？カレーを作っている。
>   例２：カレーは子供立ちが作っている。 --> **誰が**カレーを作っている？子供たちだ。

「誰が」・「どこで」・「どのように」などのような情報を特に強調したい時には「は」を使うことは多いと思うんだが、「を」と「が」だけが完全に代行されている。「に」・「で」・「と」・「へ」があったら、その時には代行をせず、助詞の後に「は」を付けるんだ。

例えば：

> Q: 17日**に**映画を見に行こうか？ A: すみません。その日**には**ちょっと用事があって。。。